# Applying Tensorflow Dataset .map() to subsequent dataset elements

Tags: tensorflow, parsing, dataset

I've got a `TFRecordDataset` and I'm trying to preprocess the features of two subsequent elements by means of the `map()` API.

```
dataset_ext = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(parse_data, [x], [tf.float32]))
```

As `map` applies the function `parse_data` to every dataset element, I don't know what `parse_data` should look like in order to keep track of the feature extracted from the previous dataset element.

Can anyone help? Thank you

EDIT: I'm working on the Waymo dataset, so each element is a frame. You can refer to https://github.com/Jossome/Waymo-open-dataset-document for its structure.

This is my parse function `parse_data`:

```
from waymo_open_dataset import dataset_pb2 as open_dataset

def parse_data(input_data):
    frame = open_dataset.Frame()
    frame.ParseFromString(bytearray(input_data.numpy()))   
    av_speed = (frame.images[0].velocity.v_x, frame.images[0].velocity.v_y, frame.images[0].velocity.v_z)
    return av_speed
```

I'd like to build a dataset whose features are the car speed and acceleration, defined as the speed variation between subsequent frames (the first value can be 0).
One way I thought about is to give the `map` function `dataset` and `dataset.skip(1)` as inputs but I'm not sure about it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but it might be unnecessary to make your mapped function a tf.py_function. How `parse_data` is supposed to look like depends on your dataset `dataset_ext`. If it has for example two file paths (1 instace of input data and 1 instance of output data), the mapping function should have 2 arguments and should return 2 arguments.

For example: if your dataset contains images and you want them to be randomly cropped each time an example of your dataset is drawn the mapping function looks like this:

```
def process_img_random_crop(img_in, img_out, output_shape):
    merged = tf.stack([img_in, img_out])
    mergedCrop = tf.image.random_crop(merged, size=(2,) + output_shape)
    img_in_cropped, img_out_cropped = tf.unstack(mergedCrop, 2, 0)
    return img_in_cropped, img_out_cropped
```

I call it as follows:

```
image_ds_test = image_ds_test.map(lambda i, o: process_img_random_crop(i, o, output_shape=(64, 64, 1)), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

What exactly is your plan with `dataset_ext` and what does it contain?

**Edit**:
Okay, got what you meant with you the two frames. So the map function is applied to each entry of your dataset separatly. If you need cross-entry information, a single entry of your dataset needs to contain two frames. With this more complicated set-up, I would suggest you to use a tensorflow `Sequence`: [The explanation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) from the tensorflow team is pretty straigth forward. Hope this help!

Comment: I've edited my question including more details. I believe I could take your suggestion and give map the original dataset and the one obtained by skipping the first element. However I'm still scratching my head over the right parse function.

Comment: Thank you, I had a look into that. A tf `Sequence` seems definitely the way to go. My concern is how to build that from a `TFRecordDataset` now. I might have just transformed my initial problem but not solved it.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like this all the time :D Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Not really, I used a little workaround. I parsed the speed features from my dataset and built a new TFRecordDataset containing speeds and accelerations. Then I just wrote a pipeline that parses data concurrently from the original dataset and the new one. It's not the most elegant solution but at least it works ;)